# KendoUI: How to open Kendo grid hyperlink column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoGrid with hyperlink column in it. The desired behavior is when I click on that column item it opens up a new tab and opens the document. This kendo grid have list of documents and will be opening up document on click on the row. I am able to open the documents by below template

```
{ title: "Name", field: "Name", template: kendo.template("<a href='" + constants.serviceUrl + "Document/GetFileContents/#= DocumentId #' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false;'>#= Name #</a>") },
```

This template works perfect as it opens up the document BUT the problem with above template is that it blows when a new document is added because at that point I do not have DocumentId.

Here is how I imagine it doing but I feel like I am missing something in this template:

```
 { title: "Name", field: "Name", template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="window.open(this.href); views.titleClick(this)" >#=Name#</a>' },
```

I have validated that both these titles hit the service layer. The above template opens up a new tab but then instead of opening document it just reloads the application. Help needed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around with pound signs I found out that we can write javascript within Kendo grid template. So before passing DocumentId I added to check to see if it is undefined.

Here is what the working code looks like:

```
  { title: "Name", field: "Name", template: kendo.template("<a href='" + constants.serviceUrl + "Document/GetFileContents/ # if (typeof(DocumentId) === 'undefined'){# -1 #} else {##= DocumentId##}#' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false;'>#= Name #</a>") },
```

Comment: I am trying your solution as follows:

    template: kendo.template("<a href='" + @Model.RATE_SHEET_URL + "{##= PriceDealProposalId ##}#' onclick='window.open(this.href);return false;'>#= PriceDealProposalId # </a>"), 

RATE_SHEET_URL value in the model is as follows:

    RATE_SHEET_URL = "http://testlink.com/RateSheet?ProposalId=";
But I am getting error: **Expected ')'**

Can you help me point out what is wrong with the way I have defined the template?